# Generate different urls on each visit(A user can use the URl just once or it expires after 2 minutes etc)

Tags: url, web

Hi
I have a url which users come and fill a form on.
Now the Issue is the url for the form is suppose www.xyz.com/form1.html
once a user comes to this url either I need the user to see a different masked url out of which he cant make out anything or he cant copy paste the url and get the same content what he has on the page he's currently on.
In short I need some source code which can mask my urls to different users clicking on the original url.
The content remains same on each url but a user cant copy paste the URL and give it to someone else to have it work a second time,either a expiration session of say 2 minutes once a user comes to that url and then he cant re-use that url again or something like that which one user can use the URl just once and not more than that.
How can I achieve this.
Please help out

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Session ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID).